# PANDAS: AND and OR between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes of the same size with boolean values. Is there a way to perform the AND, OR or XOR functions between the two dataframes?

for example

df1:

```
[False, True, False]  
[True,  False, True]
```

df2:

```
[True, False, False]      
[True, False, False]
```

df1 OR df2

```
[True, True, False]
[True, False,True ]
```

Comment: `df1 & df2` for `AND` and `df1 | df2` for `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `numpy.logical_and` and `numpy.logical_or` for this task, i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[False,True,False],[True,False,True]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[True,False,False],[True,False,False]])
dfor = np.logical_or(df1,df2)
print(dfor)
```

output

```
      0      1      2
0  True   True  False
1  True  False   True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({1: [False, True, False], 2: [True,  False, True]})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({1: [True, False, False], 2: [True, False, False]})
```

Using OR:

```
resulting_dataframe_using_OR = pandas.DataFrame({1: (df1[1]|df2[1]), 2: (df1[2]|df2[2])})
```

Output using OR:

```
       1      2
0   True   True
1   True  False
2  False   True
```

Using AND:

```
resulting_dataframe_using_AND = pandas.DataFrame({1: (df1[1]&df2[1]), 2: (df1[2]&df2[2])})
```

Output using AND:

```
       1      2
0  False   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
```